# Is there a way to store mapping between attributes in graphml?

Tags: python, graph, igraph, networkx, graphml

I have a graph, in which I need to store multiple node attributes. Two of the attributes have one to one correspondence, i.e key-value relation. If I store them as different attributes, I cannnot enforce the mapping and the mapping doesnt get reflected. If I store one of them as a attribute of the other ass shown below, none of the graph libraries including `networkx` and `igraph`, read the attribute.

Sample of the desired graphML node storing

```
 <graph edgedefault="directed">
    <node id="1">
      <data key="d0">-10</data>
      <data key="lemma" globVal=5394 >viSram</data>
    </node>
    <node id="2">
      <data key="lemma" globVal=2342>BAvay</data>
      <data key="d0">-23</data>
    </node>
```

Is such a kind of rerpresentation possible in graphMl, which networkx or igraph accepts?